# Visual Studio can't find IIS Express

Tags: c#

I'm a student and my project is this website.

But I accidently deleted the IIS Express file. And now I get this error. I uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio and IIS Express is in the right folder and yet this error shows up. How do I make Visual Studio know where the right folder for IIS Express is? How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. all you need to do is **uninstall** the ISS Express in the control panel, and than **install** it again from **https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264**